# Aura Component - Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback()

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, callback

I have one Aura component created in 2019 by previous developer. This is dynamicPicklist which is taking records as values.

Sometimes after refresh I am getting error:

> Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read properties of null (setting 'value')]
> Callback failed: apex://DynamicPickListController/ACTION$getExistingValues

I figure it out that problem is in `DynamicPickListHelper.js`, but I am not able to find what is wrong with it. The bug is shown only sometimes and this is only popup - this bug is not change anything.

The error is on 58 line:

```javascript
    else {
        console.log("Failed with state: " + state);
    }
```

Here is the whole code:

Helper.js

```javascript
action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
    var state = response.getState();
    if (state === "SUCCESS") {
        console.log('Test',response.getReturnValue());
        component.set('v.ctrlListVal', response.getReturnValue());
        var dynamicCtrlList = component.get("v.ctrlListVal");
        var fieldsList = [];
        var selectedMap = new Map(); 
        for(var i=0; i<dynamicCtrlList.length; i++) {
            var fieldName = dynamicCtrlList[i].fieldName;
            fieldsList[i] =fieldName;
        }
        var action = component.get("c.getExistingValues");
        action.setParams({
            "objectID": component.get("v.recordId"),
            "fieldsListParam": fieldsList
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set('v.finalStringVal', response.getReturnValue()); 
                var returnVal =component.get('v.finalStringVal');
                console.log('returnVal',returnVal);
                if(returnVal != undefined && returnVal != '') {
                    var res = returnVal.split("$");
                    for(var i=0;i<res.length;i++) {
                        var res1 = res[i].split("&");
                        if(res1 !=  undefined && res1 != '') {
                            if(res1[1] != 'null')
                                document.getElementById(res1[0]).value=res1[1];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                console.log("Failed with state: " + state);
            }
        });
        // Send action off to be executed
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
    else {
        console.log("Failed with state: " + state);
    } 
});
// Send action off to be executed
$A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

Apex Class:

```apex
public with sharing class DynamicPickListController {
    @AuraEnabled public Map<String, List<String>> FieldValueMapVal;
    @AuraEnabled public List<Dynamic_Pick_List__c> dynamicPiclIst ;
    @AuraEnabled public String fieldName;
    @AuraEnabled public List<String> valuesList;
    @AuraEnabled public String fieldLabel;
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<DynamicPickListController> getDetailsFromDynamicPickList(Id objectID) {
        List<DynamicPickListController> ctrlList = new List<DynamicPickListController>();
        List<Dynamic_Pick_List__c> dynamicList = new List<Dynamic_Pick_List__c>();
        Map<String, List<String>> FieldValueMap = new Map<String, List<String>>();
        String objectType = objectID.getSObjectType() + '';
        String newSearchText = '%' + objectType + '%';
        String userCompanyCode = [SELECT Company_Code__c FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId() limit 1].Company_Code__c;
        dynamicList =  [Select Id, Dynamic_Pick_List__c.Object__c, Dynamic_Pick_List__c.Field__c, Values__c, Order__c, CompanyCode__c from Dynamic_Pick_List__c where Object__c Like :newSearchText and CompanyCode__c = :userCompanyCode ORDER BY Order__c ASC];
        Map<String, List<String>> mapValues = new  Map<String, List<String>>();
        if (!dynamicList.isEmpty()) {
            for (Dynamic_Pick_List__c d : dynamicList) {
                if (!mapValues.keySet().contains(d.Field__c)) {
                    List<String> valList = new List<String>();
                    valList.add(d.Values__c);
                    mapValues.put(d.Field__c, valList);
                } else {
                    List<String> valList = mapValues.get(d.Field__c);
                    valList.add(d.Values__c);
                    mapValues.put(d.Field__c, valList);
                }
            }
        }
        if (mapValues != null && mapValues.size() > 0) {
            for (String s : mapValues.keySet()) {
                DynamicPickListController ctrl = new DynamicPickListController();
                if (isPermission(objectType, s)) {
                    ctrl.fieldName = s;
                    ctrl.fieldLabel = getLabelForField(objectType, s);
                    ctrl.valuesList = mapValues.get(s);
                    ctrlList.add(ctrl);
                }
            }
        }
        System.debug('ctrlList' + ctrlList);
        return ctrlList;
    }
    
    private static string getLabelForField(String objectName, String fieldName) {
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
        Schema.SObjectType leadSchema = schemaMap.get(objectName);
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = leadSchema.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
        return fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getLabel();
    }
    
    private static Boolean isPermission(String objectName, String fieldName) {
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
        Schema.SObjectType leadSchema = schemaMap.get(objectName);
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = leadSchema.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
        return fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().isUpdateable();
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String SaveRecords (Id objectID, Map<String, Object> fieldNameValMap) {
        List<Dynamic_Pick_List__c> dpList = new List<Dynamic_Pick_List__c>();
        String objectType = objectID.getSObjectType() + '';
        String soqlQuery = 'Select Id';
        for (String s : fieldNameValMap.keySet())
            soqlQuery = soqlQuery + ',' + s;
            soqlQuery = soqlQuery + ' From ' + objectType + ' where Id = ';
            soqlQuery = soqlQuery + '\'' + objectID + '\'' + ' Limit 1' ;
            sObject s = Database.query(soqlQuery);
            for (String s1 : fieldNameValMap.keySet())
                s.put(s1, fieldNameValMap.get(s1) + '');
                String newSearchText = '%' + objectType + '%';
                String userCompanyCode = [SELECT Company_Code__c FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId() limit 1].Company_Code__c;
                dpList =  [Select Id,Name,ID_Field__c, Object__c, Field__c, Values__c, Order__c, CompanyCode__c from Dynamic_Pick_List__c where Object__c Like :newSearchText and CompanyCode__c = :userCompanyCode ORDER BY Order__c ASC];
                for(Dynamic_Pick_List__c d: dpList) {
                    if(fieldNameValMap.containsKey(d.Field__c)) {
                        if(!String.isEmpty(d.Values__c) && !String.isEmpty(d.ID_Field__c) && fieldNameValMap.get(d.Field__c) ==  d.Values__c)
                            s.put(d.ID_Field__c,d.Name);
                    }
                }
                Database.updateAsync(s);
                return 'Your changes are saved.';
            }
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String getExistingValues (Id objectID, List<String>fieldsListParam) {
        Map<String, String> selectedValue = new Map<String, String>() ;
        String finalString = '';
        String objectType = objectID.getSObjectType() + '';
        String newSearchText = '%' + objectType + '%';
        String soqlQuery = 'Select Id';
        for (String s : fieldsListParam)
          soqlQuery = soqlQuery + ',' + s;
        soqlQuery = soqlQuery + ' From ' + objectType + ' where Id = ';
        soqlQuery = soqlQuery + '\'' + objectID + '\'' + ' Limit 1' ;
        sObject sobj = Database.query(soqlQuery);
        for (String s : fieldsListParam) {
            //selectedValue.put(s,sobj.get(s)+'');
            if (String.isEmpty(finalString))
                finalString = finalString + s + '&' + sobj.get(s) + '';
            else
                finalString = finalString + '$' + s + '&' + sobj.get(s) + '';
        }
        return finalString;
    }
}
```

Controller.js

```javascript
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.fetchDetails(component, event, helper);
    },
    saveValues: function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.saveValuesinObject(component, event, helper);
    }
})
```

Can somebody help me with it?

Comment: Please post code where you are setting params to action and apex controller code as well

Comment: @amitghadage done :)